# Episerver block button

Tags: episerver

Is it possible add button with link to other page into block setting?
I mean 
[Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmjcz.png)

I need a button in the content or settings section, which brings me to another page on click.

Thank you

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What I want to archive is, in the block settings, as can be seen in the picture, I want to place button there, which I want to take me to some url, which will be set programaticaly. The button could be in either content, or settings, or maybe another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a view for that block type (just as you would for any other block type) and insert the link there. Editors would be able to click the link while in on-page editing mode for the settings block.

If you want to insert it into the Episerver UI, you could create a custom Dojo widget.

Comment: Yes, I made a new view, and it suits the purpose better. Thanks :)

Comment: http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Duong-Nguyen/Dates/2013/12/Custom-views-and-plugin-areas-in-EPiServer-75/ and there is very nice tutorial for that, if any one needs that